# Back button restoring clicks

Tags: jquery, button, filter, back

So I have a back button on my site, I think it is a typical one :

```
<a href="javascript:history.back(1)">back</a>
```

However, I have a gallery of images, filtered with jQuery, and when you click the back button, I would like the filter to stay activated - and it doesn't, of course.

So any ideas how to make the previously selected filter stay in place ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code: `<a href="#" onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;"> Link </a>`